# How to find if a USB has been plugged in on a certain date? (Linux/Mac)

Tags: security, logs, usb

Starting from this great script offered by Daniel Azuelos

```
cd /Volumes/suspicious_USB  
/usr/bin/sudo find . -atime -21 -exec ls -dluT {} \;
```

How is it possible to modify it in order to find if a USB flash was plugged in, on any random computer, on a certain date? Say, for instance, May the 3rd? Any way to detect if a file was opened or copied?

Both Linux and Mac terminal scripts would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Concerning your first question "find if a USB flash was plugged in", the kernel will report the insertion of USB storage devices.

Example below, which assumes your Linux distro is using `systemd` (other distros may write to `/var/log/messages` or similar file instead).

```
# journalctl --since '2018-05-19' --until '2018-05-20' | grep 'kernel: usb'
May 19 12:22:15 localhost.localdomain kernel: usb 1-1.1.1: USB disconnect, device number 7
May 19 12:22:19 localhost.localdomain kernel: usb 1-1.1.1: new high-speed USB device number 8 using ehci-pci
May 19 12:22:19 localhost.localdomain kernel: usb 1-1.1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=13fe, idProduct=1f00
May 19 12:22:19 localhost.localdomain kernel: usb 1-1.1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
May 19 12:22:19 localhost.localdomain kernel: usb 1-1.1.1: Product: Patriot Memory
May 19 12:22:19 localhost.localdomain kernel: usb 1-1.1.1: Manufacturer:         
May 19 12:22:19 localhost.localdomain kernel: usb 1-1.1.1: SerialNumber: 07870CA23F48
May 19 12:22:19 localhost.localdomain kernel: usb-storage 1-1.1.1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
#
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes; there are some indicators that might exist.

No; there is no way to prevent a savvy user form avoiding detection.

The storrage

- The most optimistic option is `find . | xargs stat | grep 2018-05-03` or for a list of times and files `find . | xargs stat -c "%x %n" | sort -r | head`
- USB flash or sdcards are likely using fat32 for compatibility which AFAIK (but easy to check with `md5sum *.img`) does not record mount count or file access time and even if a more advanced a file system were used the data can be copied at the block level (`cat /dev/sdb > backup_$(date --iso-8601).img`).
- USB flash or sdcards typically have none of the hardware management of HDD/SSD/EMMC/NVMe which would normally log usage (visible with `smartctl -a /dev/sdb`) and even those can be bypassed by temporarily swapping controller boards.
- Getting portable storage with properly implemented logging, encryption, and TPM would require taking apart a chip and possibly a $60k electron microscope to read undetected (replacing the chip with a new one).

The computer

- The most optimistic option is `dmesg -T | grep "New USB device found" | grep "May 03"` but `dmesg -c` etc can clear that.
- If you had root and they did not you could use log shipping to keep track but they could just boot from a usb live distrobution to avoid that.

Sample output;

```
2018-05-19 04:57:13.723849533 -0400 ./yum.sh
2018-05-18 17:00:01.271971441 -0400 ./food.sh
```

.

```
[Mon May 14 19:44:19 2018] usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[Mon May 14 19:44:19 2018] usb usb3: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0001
```